# Update column based on combination of other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that includes the following columns and data:

```
Invoice #       Quantity     Item Id
21589              265        L-s20-02-0
```

In this instance there are 265 records with the same information. I want to be able to update the quantity column to 1 if there are the same amount of records as the quantity. In this instance if there are 265 records that match the same Invoice#, Quantity and Item ID

Answer (score 2):

This is a curious request, but it is possible using window functions:

```
;WITH toupdate AS (
      SELECT t.*,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY invoice, item, quantity) AS cnt
      FROM t
     )
UPDATE toupdate
    SET quantity = 1
    WHERE cnt = quantity;
```